# How to login django-custom-user in admin panel?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-login, django-custom-user, django-custom-manager

3 Types of Users with different Login Systems.

1. Student : Uses unique student_id and password for login.
2. SchoolAdmin: Uses email and password for login.
3. Developer (Team): Uses email and password for login and is able to login in admin panel.

Here is My BaseUser

```
class BaseUSER(AbstractBaseUser):

  email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)

  USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

Here is My user no.1 the student

```
class StudentUser(BaseUSER):

  student_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=10)
  address = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
  city = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True, null=True)
  state = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
  pincode = models.CharField(max_length=6,blank=True, null=True)
  email_id =  models.EmailField(blank=True)
  phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
  mother_phone = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
  father_phone = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
  standard = models.CharField(max_length=2,blank=True, null=True)
  # bus_transport = models.ForeignKey(Bus,blank=True,null=True)

  USERNAME_FIELD = 'student_id'
```

Here is My user no.2 SchoolAdmin

```
class SchoolAdmin(BaseUSER):

  school = models.ForeignKey(School,blank=True,null=True)

  objects = NewUserManager()

  USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

Here is my user no. 3 the developer team (That need access to admin panel)

```
class team(BaseUSER):

  pin_level = models.CharField(max_length=10)

  def get_full_name(self):
    return self.first_name
```

I have created different user manager for each

UserManager for School Admin

```
class NewUserManager(BaseUserManager):

  use_in_migrations = True

  def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
    """
    Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
    """
    if not email:
        raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
    email = self.normalize_email(email)
    user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

  def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
    return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

User Manager for developer team:

```
class SuperManager(BaseUserManager):


  use_in_migrations = True

  def get_by_natural_key(self, email):
    return self.get(**{self.model.USERNAME_FIELD: email})

  def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
    """
    Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
    """
    if not email:
        raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
    email = self.normalize_email(email)
    user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    user.is_admin = True
    return user

  def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
    return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


  def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
    if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
        raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')
    return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

I have also created a authentication backend for email login

Please Advice me if I am wrong some where, 
what I need to do and what should be my further approach as I am struck here,

I want to implement Login for Admin Panel and the user that should be able to login is from type 3 or team.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking

Comment: Exactly. Tell us where are you stuck ?

Comment: I am not able to login in admin panel

Comment: did you specified [AUTH_USER_MODEL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) in settings? You may try to specify it to your `team` model, not 100% percent sure that it will work, but I think it is worth to try

Comment: it did not work

Comment: Did any body get Any Solution ??